# IF Function Not Populating Correct Data in Excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I am completely stumped as to why this formula is not working properly. To provide backstory, I am  trying to randomize a DMS grid coordinate, for example: `2339**01**N05005**51**W`. I only want to randomize the `MID(5,2)` and `MID(13,2)` in bold, but I need to make sure other values change if not between `0` and `60`.

1. I have the number I want set to randomize 5 digits up or down:
   `=AH3+(RANDBETWEEN(-5,5))`
2. I perform a check formula (for visual and next step) and change formula on this number if `AJ3` is `< 0` and `> 59`:

   ```
   =IF(AJ3<0,"LESS",IF(AJ3>59,"MORE","GOOD"))
   =IF(AJ3<0,AJ3+60,IF(AJ3>59,AJ3-60,AJ3))
   ```

2.1. In this case, when randomized on the LAT Seconds `01` I can see the changes made if the digit falls into the negative number range. So -2 changes to `58` and states `LESS` in those respective formula cells.

3. Now from the check formula in step 2. That formula above allows me to identify subtracting 1, adding 1, or leaving the same to the `LAT-Minutes 23**39**01N0500551W`, or `MID(3,2)` values:

   ```
   =IF(AK3="MORE",AG3+1,IF(AK3="GOOD",AG3,IF(AK3="LESS",AG3-1)))
   ```

3.1. This works, it will change the 39 value to 38.

**I am stuck at this part:**
4. The next IF Function I am using for checks does not work properly.

```
 =IF(AM3<0,"LESS",IF(AM3>59,"MORE","GOOD"))
```

- Anytime the number from the previous formula ends in a `9` (e.g. `09,19,29,39,49,59`), the cell reads `MORE`. It does not have this issue with any other number value between `00` and `59`. It seems like the issue is deriving the value from the previous formula. When I apply this formula to a cell without formulas, it will work properly. I have even tried creating another cell to just =the formula cell from step 3, but no prevail.

Anyone have any thoughts on this? -Or have a better solution on how I can randomize a DMS coordinate between `0,59` in the seconds column, which rounds up the minutes column between `0,59`, and lastly the degrees column between `0,90` for `LAT` and `0,180` for `LON`? That is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

## BACKGROUND

In Excel mapping coordinates in Degrees Decimal (DD) format are as easy to manipulate as any other decimal numbers.  The Degrees/Minutes/Seconds (DMS) format makes things more complex since one can't add numbers to text without manipulating it first:
`TEN + 2 != 12`

##### Straightforward DD Math

```
Longitude + x,  // or Latitude
where RAND(x) >= -0.001388889 AND RAND(x)<= 0.001388889
```

##### DD   (#)

```
 Eiffel Tower DD
 ------------------------------
 48.85948189, -2.293305111

 +5 DMS Seconds DD
 ------------------------------
 48.859481890,  -2.293305111
 +0.001388889,  +0.001388889
 ============   ============
 48.860870779,  -2.291916222

 -5 DMS Seconds DD 
 ------------------------------
 48.860870779,  -2.291916222
 -0.001388889,  -0.001388889
 ============   ============
 48.858093001,  -2.294694000
```

##### DMS Strings Make Math Complicated

Converting from DMS values makes the math a lot more complex.

1. DMS is a string that first needs to be split into the latitude (LA) and longitude (LO)
2. LA/LO strings need to be parsed for degrees, minutes, seconds
3. Degrees strings could be 1-3 digits long
4. Seconds strings could be 2-x digits depending on the precision (e.g. Eiffel Tower LA is 29.1348 DMS seconds
5. LA/LO strings need to be parsed for N,S,E,W, values to determine if they are positive or negative numbers
6. While DD to DMS is considerably simpler there is some formatting to watch for like single digit minute/second DMS values as two digit strings "0#".

##### DMS   (text)

```
 Eiffel Tower DMS (Various)
 -------------------------------
 48° 51' 29.1348'' N, 2° 17' 40.8984'' W  
 48 51 29.1348 N, 2 17 40.8984 W  
 485129.1348N, 21740.8984W  
 485129.1348N21740.8984W (the format you shared)

 +5 Seconds DMS
 ------------------------------
 00° 00' 05'' N, 00° 00' 05'' E

 -5 Seconds DMS
 ------------------------------
 00° 00' 05'' S, 00° 00' 05'' W
```

---

## ANSWER

There are a number of steps to complete in order to take a string, break it apart, convert it to a number, perform calculations, then convert it back to a DMS string again.  I have edited my answer to try to reduce the code and improve readability.  I have broken out key functions into Excel `named formulas` to make it more modular and easier to follow.

#### FORMULA: DMS in, DMS Out

```
where Cell A3=DMS Formatted Mapping Coordinates

1| =LET(input,$A$3,                                                           
2|    dms,TRIM(ReplaceChars(input,"',   °`","")),
3|    dmsLatOut,dd2dms((dms2dd(dmsFromBoth(dms,1))+(RANDBETWEEN(-5,5)/3600)),1),
4|    dmsLonOut,dd2dms((dms2dd(dmsFromBoth(dms,2))+(RANDBETWEEN(-5,5)/3600)),2),
5|    dmsLatOut&dmsLonOut)
```

#### NAMED FUNCTIONS USED

##### ReplaceChars

```
=LAMBDA(str,chars,sub, IF(chars="",str, ReplaceChars( SUBSTITUTE(str,LEFT(chars),sub), MID(chars,2,LEN(chars)-1), sub)))

Loops through a string (str) and substitutes each specified character (chars) with another string (sub where Len(sub)=>0).
NB: if chars="and" then all "a" + all "n" + all "d" will be replaced.
Based on: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/write-recursive-lambda-function-excel/
```

##### dmsFromBoth

```
=LAMBDA(x,coord, IF(coord=2,IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("W",x)>0,-1,),1)*(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(x, (ABS(LAfromBoth(x))&IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("N",x)>0,"N",),"S")),""),LEN(x)-LEN(ABS(LAfromBoth(x)))-2)),LAfromBoth(x)))

Extracts the DMS Latitude (coord=1 [Default]) or Longitude (coord=2) from a combined DMS value (x)
```

##### LAfromBoth

```
=LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(LEFT(x,SEARCH("N",x)-1)*1,LEFT(x,SEARCH("S",x)-1)*-1))

Extracts the DMS Latitude from a combined DMS value (x)
```

##### dms2dd

```
=LAMBDA(x, SUM(TRUNC((x/(10^(4+(IF(LEN(TRUNC(x))=5,-1,0)))))),TRUNC(((x/(10^(4+(IF(LEN(TRUNC(x))=5,-1,0)))))-TRUNC((x/(10^(4+(IF(LEN(TRUNC(x))=5,-1,0)))))))*100)/60,(((((x/100)-TRUNC(x/100))*100))/3600)))

Converts any positive or negative Latitude or Longitude DMS Value to DD
```

##### dd2dms

```
=LAMBDA(x,coord, ABS(TRUNC(x))&TEXT(ABS(TRUNC((x-(TRUNC(x)))*60)),"0#")&TEXT(ABS((((x-(TRUNC(x)))*60)-TRUNC((x-(TRUNC(x)))*60))*60),"0#.####")&IF(coord=2,IF(x>0,"E","W"),IF(x>0,"N","S")))

Converts a Latitude (coord=1 [Default]) or Longitude (coord=2) DD value x to DMS
```

## MY 2¢

Very interesting problem space.  Appreciated the opportunity to learn about GPS as well as Named Functions  in Excel.  At first glance, using time calculations with Degrees/Minutes/Seconds (DMS) values seemed like the way to go since time functions already address the rollover of seconds to minutes, minutes to hours, etc.  However, I quickly switched to Decimal Degrees (DD) because it was infinitely easier to work with coordinates as decimal values than try to force them into Excel's time functions.

Based on my experience I would think that **mapping coordinates should be stored, retrieved, and manipulated in DD format and only converted as needed**. Conversion to DMS might be helpful for display (readability), or as needed for another application.